# How does one specify type parameters to the primary constructor in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin

In Java I can do something like this:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class Foo {
    public final String s;

    // Parameters to constructor are generic, but constrained
    public <K> Foo(List<K> list, Map<K, String> map) {
        // Compute something from those parameters where result
        // has type independent of input type parameters.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (K k : list) {
            sb.append(map.get(k));
        }
        s = sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Note that the `Foo` class has no type parameters, but its constructor has type parameters. Can something equivalent be done in Kotlin?

Comment: Do you have a use case in mind that requires this instead of generics on the class itself?  What is the purpose of generics that do not constrain anything in the constructor?

Comment: @JaysonMinard That was a pared-down example to try and keep things simple, but apparently I went too far. I've changed the example to something a bit more realistic that hopefully illustrates why I might want constructor type parameters that do not turn into class type parameters.

Comment: I think @yole's suggestion covers your case, factory method.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin does not support type parameters for constructors, so you can define a factory function instead:

```
class Foo private constructor(val s: String) {
     companion object {
         fun <K> create(list: List<K>, map: Map<K, String>) =
               Foo(list.map { map[it] }.joinToString(""))
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java

```
public class Bar<K,V> {
  public final int x;

  public Bar(Map<K, V> map) {
    x = map.hashCode();
  }
}
```

equivalent in Kotlin

```
class Bar <K,V> constructor (map: Map<K,V>) {
    val x = map.hashCode()
}
```

In Java

```
public class Bar {
  public final int x;

  public Bar(Map map) {
    x = map.hashCode();
  }
}
```

equivalent in Kotlin

```
class Bar constructor (map: Map<*, *>) {
    val x = map.hashCode()
}
```

In Java

```
public class Bar {
  public final int x;

  public <K, V>Bar(Map<K, V> map) {
    x = map.hashCode();
  }
}
```

equivalent in Kotlin

```
// no way to do so
```

According to Kotlin [garmmer](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#primaryConstructor), there is no equivalent in implementation in Kotlin because we cannot define Type Parameters in primary nor secondary constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in the Java code I'd posted originally. I just corrected it. You don't need type parameters on the class in Java, as you can put type parameters on the constructor.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves Just checked the kotlin [grammer](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#secondaryConstructor)
There is no way to do so.

Comment: Is Kotlin's `Map<*, *>` really like a raw `Map` in Java, or is it more like the wildcard `Map<?, ?>`?

Comment: If it's really true that Kotlin can't do this -- that seems unfortunate. Any ideas on how to convert the new example code I just posted?